The Jehovah's Witnesses say millions living in the past will gain salvation at the 2nd coming of Jesus Christ. The Bible contradicts that teaching
The source can be find here: https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/faq/who-saved/

Do Jehovah’s Witnesses Feel That They Are the Only People Who Will Be Saved?


No. Many millions who lived in centuries past and who weren’t Jehovah’s Witnesses will have an opportunity for salvation. The Bible explains that in God’s promised new world, “there is going to be a resurrection of both the righteous and the unrighteous.” (Acts 24:15) Additionally, many now living may yet begin to serve God, and they too will gain salvation. In any case, it’s not our job to judge who will or won’t be saved. That assignment rests squarely in Jesus’ hands.—John 5:22, 27."

How do they reconcile this viewpoint when the Bible teaches that people received/gain salvation by believing in Jesus Christ as their Savior centuries before the second coming of Jesus Christ?
Romans 10:8-10, "But what does it say? "The Word is near you, in your mouth and in your heart--that is, the word of faith which we are preaching, vs9, that if you confess with your mouth Jesus as Lord and believe in your heart that God raised Him from the dead, you will be saved; vs10, for with the heart man believes resulting in righteousness, and with the mouth he confesses resulting in salvation."

Can you copy and paste the answers you didn’t like when you deleted this same question an hour or so ago? It’s not fair to thr users who took time to answer the convoluted mess of s question yiu asked before to delete the whole thing and re ask.   Just edit the old one and undelete it!  Then delete this one

I already tried to edit the original question which included all the answers two times but it would not let me post it. I spent time on my answers as well. Since I simplified the question how about reconciling your teaching with what the Bible teaches. And as a side note, my question had nothing to do with "once saved always saved." Answer this question, does
Romans 10:8-10 contradict what you teach?

Undelete the old one. I will edit this exact question into its place

The millions who are spoken of as getting a chance at salvation did not have an opportunity to do what Roman’s 10 is saying

@007. I'm leaving this thread alone, it's simplified. Your answer is according to Jw teaching, not what the Bible actually says and teaches. Look at Romans 10:11-13, "For the Scriptures says, "Whoever believes in Him will not be disappointed, vs12, "For there is no distinction  between Jew and Greek; for the same Lord is Lord of all, abounding in riches for all who call upon Him; vs13, "for Whoever will call upon the name of the Lord will be saved." Come on 007, this means now or everyday people call upon the Lord to be saved. Who told you that these people have to wait until the 2nd coming?

@Mr.Bond I didn’t  answer either of your questions. But the dead cannot do what Roman’s 10 tells the living to do. Those millions who lived and died with no opportunity to believe in the lord Jesus are the ones who get the chance to do so after they are resurrected

Well that's your choice! Is there a reason you did not answer the questions?

I do not answer your questions because you never upvote or accept any jw answer

I only vote up or down based on whether or not the question/answer is based on the Bible. You also said the other day, "why are you so angry?" I'm not an angry persons and what I say about a person and how I feel about them are two different things." As a Christian, I love you for Christ's sake and if one is a Christian and they don't hate sin then there is something wrong with their Christianity. None of this business is games, it's serious business that has to do with where you are going to spend eternity. This is my mindset. Read 1 Corinthians 2:16. Getting down votes does not bother me.

Mr bond said “I only vote up or down based on whether or not the question/answer is based on the Bible. “ Therefore I encourage all who are thinking about answering one of his question to understand that he is not asking in good faith but only to start debates  he should be put on hold to teach him a lesson.

@007 Well that's a real mature answer! And what do you base your questions and answers on? Is it not strictly based on your organizations writings and literature? I know, teach this "goat" like one a lesson.

When you ask for a jw answer expect a jw sourced answer that’s how this site is designed to work

"How do they reconcile this viewpoint when the Bible teaches that …" — again, it's not clear why you think the two statements are contradictory. What exactly is the conflict?

And again, why pick on the JWs? They aren't the only denomination that believes "there is going to be a resurrection of both the righteous and the unrighteous".

@RayButterworth You still don't get it. I too personally believe there will be a resurrection of both the righteous and the unrighteous. The problem is they teach people will gain salvation after the 2nd coming of Christ.  To them no one is saved presently/today or back in Jesus' time, after His resurrection.  For example, you Ray claim to be a Christian. According to them your not a Christian until Jesus comes back and He determines/judges whether or not your righteous or unrighteous. Of course this teaching is false because people were saved on the spot starting at the book of Acts.

"they teach people will gain salvation after the 2nd coming of Christ" — They aren't the only such denomination. ¶ "According to them you're not a Christian until Jesus comes back" — No, only that Christians aren't reborn and given immortality until then. ¶ "people were saved on the spot starting at the book of Acts" — No, not saved. They accepted God's holy spirit to help them develop God-like character. They could later reject this gift. Compare with being pulled into a life raft, and later deciding to swim. ¶ "you claim to be a Christian" — I don't believe I've ever said either way.

@RayButterworth Who taught you this unbiblical doctrine? Reconcile your view with the following verses? Galatians 3:2, did you receive the Spirit by the works of the Law, or by the hearing of faith. Galatians 4:6, "And because you are sons, God has sent forth the Spirit of His Son INTO OUR HEARTS, crying, "Abba! Father!" Read Romans 8:9-11, Ephesians 1:13-14, 1 John 5:13, Galatians 1:6-9. And here's an oldie but goody, Ephesians 2:8 "For by grace you have been saved (past tense) through faith; and that not of yourselves, it is the gift of God." What church do you attend that teaches your view?

Let's keep the comments restricted to clarifying the post.A remind that the purpose of this site is to provide information about what people believe, not determine who is right and who is wrong.

@Mr.Bond. There's nothing in the scriptures you quoted that contradicts anything I've said. The only contradiction in this whole thing is caused by your implicit once-saved-always-saved belief, a doctrine that isn't accepted by many major denominations.

@Mr.Bond, You quote a specific translation of Ephesians 2:8.  Compare "For by grace are ye saved through faith", which is similar in meaning to "For by skill and determination are you champions" which might be said to a sports team before the game. It is a rule to help keep the goal in mind, to inspire hard work and perseverance.

@RayButterworth Ok, how about Ephesians 1:13-14, "In Him,, you also, after listening to the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation--having also believed, you were sealed (past tense) in Him WITH THE HOLY SPIRIT OF PROMISE, vs14, who is GIVEN AS A PLEDGE of our inheritance, with the view to the redemption of Gods own possession, to the praise of His glory." This means the down payment we have received is the Holy Spirit himself (Romans 8:9,16).  His indwelling presence is a guarantee that God will consummate all His promises to us when the proper times arrives. What sport applies here?

@Mr.Bond, no one is denying that people receive God's holy spirit at baptism, which seems to be the only argument you present.  But this is is hardly the place for you to defend your personal view of a doctrine that you won't explicitly mention, which barely existed before the Reformation, and which is rejected by the Catholic, Orthodox, and many Protestant Churches.

@RayButterworth I'm not giving you my personal view, I'm giving you what the Bible says and teaches at Ephesians 1:13-14. I also referenced Romans 8:9,16.  Your the one giving your personal view which is unbiblical. I can also provide 10 or more other verses that support what I'm saying. One excellent one is at Acts 10:44-48. And btw, spirit baptism is a separate event after salvation. You can read about it here: https://enrichmentjournal.ag.org/Issues/2010/Spring-2010/Teaching-on-Spirit-Baptism-as-a-Separate-Event-After-Salvation  Instead of changing the subject address the verses?

Jehovah's Witnesses are premillennial. They believe in a literal 1000 year reign of Jesus Christ prior to the final judgement.
So one possible way that they reconcile it is by believing that salvation is possible in the millennium.
I.e., Jesus comes back to establish His Kingdom, there is a first resurrection, and people who did not believe in Him will have an opportunity to repent.
In the premillennial view, there will be a final rebellion at the end of the millennium, followed by a final judgement where Satan is defeated forever. At this point there is no possibility for sinners to repent.
